# View could not be restored when using Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, jsf

I am trying a simple example of JSF. It's just a test page for JSF with a label and command button. My command button will trigger a POST request and execute an action in the backing bean. Whenever I click the command button, I always encounter an error:

```
View /index.xhtml could not be restored
```

Now, this only occurs on Chrome. It works fine on other browsers such as IE and FireFox. It even works on Chrome if it is in Incognito Mode.

Adding the following code in web.xml fixes the Chrome's issue:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatability</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But I still wonder why I only encounter the exception during chrome. I hope someone can clear this out for me. Thank you in advance!

Edit:
The only difference I found when requesting the page is in the cookie:

```
Chrome:
Cookie:JSESSIONID=hkwfGUG-nQjCJTBh8dUeOFSz; searchMode=SEARCH; lastFolderUri=/themes; JSESSIONID=9C193DCE1E4412E9E4D7EF6645BE4CBF

Chrome (Incognito Mode):
Cookie:JSESSIONID=I1eusBuy_3nODrV1DaKKGBlF
```

I don't know why non incognito Chrome has multiple JSESSIONIDs.

Comment: Apparently Chrome does something differently. If you really want to know, sniff the HTTP requests being sent back and forth and look for differences between Chrome and another browser.

Comment: post your index.html and your backing bean code